# jQuery - Twitter Bootstrap - dropdown menu always visible

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with [Twitter Bootstrap dropdowns menu](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns) and trying to change behavior of this part: when I click on the link with Dropdowns menu, I'll get the submenu. When I click into the displayed submenu, so the submenu will be hide.

I would like to have the submenu visible also that time, when I click into this submenu. 
How to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing something like this.

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){

   $('.dropdown-menu a').css({'display' : 'block' });

});
```

Or take a look at the plugin and see which function is hiding the menu when clicking the submenu link, and then tap into that using your own script.